# How to npm update only one specific package but not its dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm developing a package for npm. So in my demo app I bounded my package as a GitHub url in the `package.json` file of my demo application:

```
"dependencies": {    
   "isojs": "dustin-H/isojs#refactor",
   /* ... */
}
```

Now when I'm changing something in `dustin-H/isojs#refactor` I update my dependency with `npm update isojs`.

This works fine, however it reloads although all sub-dependencies of `isojs`, which takes more time than just updating my own package.

Is there any way to just update my own package and do not reload the other sub packages?

Comment: What version of npm are you using? Versions as of 2.6.1 will only update top-level packages, [see the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update).

Comment: Ah, I've just realised you are updating your package *directly*, which means it would still update the top-level packages of that package (which you want to avoid). Hmm not sure that's possible, at least I can't see anything in the docs about it.

Comment: I also read the docs and googled and could't find anything, so I thought I ask here. May there is a secret function or something ;)